# How do I sell complete LEGO sets still assembled?

Tags: shopping, disassembly

I have several complete items I want to sell. I have the instruction manuals but no boxes. They are still together. They include the old Death Star, and some other Star Wars, the complete Lone Ranger set and more.
How do I do this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Brick SE. Have you tried to use the seach function? "sell LEGO" yields some interesting hints about how sell your sets. Ebay or Bricklink are common answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can list the on BrickLink as complete, used, no box. Those are options you can select as you list each set. You can also list them on eBay, and just put in the description that the sets are without box, but with instructions and all the pieces included. This is a normal and accepted way of selling LEGO sets.